# Java EE Upload Location

Tags: java, deployment, web

Right, I've managed to get my upload problem working, but I'm hitting a new wall. I decided against storing in a database, but now the problem I am having is how to save the image, in such a way that's it not deleted if it's redeployed.

I am using the following to get the local context

```
     ServletContext sc = request.getSession().getServletContext();
String path = sc.getRealPath("images");
```

I am then creating the directory based on the name of the item created (in this project, it's Designer\Garment Type\Garment Name\image.jpg)

However, this is saving in

Project\Project\dist\gfdeploy\Project\Project-war_war

where ideally I want it in

Project\Project\Project-war\web which is where the index file is located.

While it's not causing an issue for now, I know it will once I actually try to get this running on a web server for real! Up until now, seeing as I only started working with Java EE about 6 weeks ago, it's all be just local, ie it was done for college projects and it just needed to work on my machine, where now I am using it to develop a site that will be going live and I want images to stay if I have to redeploy or change things after launch.

Being honest, I have no idea how to deploy this, so if anything I am saying doesn't make sense, let me know or if there's somewhere that helps me to deploy this when the time comes, I would greatly, greatly appreciate it. I was talking to my cousin who has worked with EE and he said to look at Maven or Ant.

Comment: Put it outside the server, and make the path configurable, either with an environment variable or a system property.

Comment: Cheers for the reply. Not really sure what you mean though.

Comment: Don't use the web project or web server as a storage area. Instead, dedicate a folder somewhere else on the file system to store your data. Then set up an environment variable or a system property that points to this folder, and use that in your application instead.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying, but when the site is live, I'll want to upload to images\web\Designers\Type\Name\image.jpg - how would I specify that in a servlet at the servlet currently uploads to where it is running from - Bear in mind that I have only taught myself to upload images a day or so ago, and I have never deploying anything to a server, other than just using my local machine as both client and server.